Google calendar events setting reminders with PHP
i'm using google/apiclient to created calendar events every thing works good except setting the event reminders still the default without any changes
here is my code snippet with PHP:
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => $service['name'],
    'description' => 'desc',
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => $google_start_time,
        'timeZone' => $timezone,
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => $google_end_time,
        'timeZone' => $timezone,
    ),
    'attendees' => array(
         array('email' => $patient['email']),
         array('email' => $provider['email']),
    ),
    'reminders' => array(
        'useDefault' => false,
        'overrides' => array(
            array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
            array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 10),
        ),
     ),
     'location' => 'location',
));

the event is created successfully with the all data in the request, but the reminders not applied
i'm using service account
can anyone help?
i tried this code but not working
